# Mutually exclusive values in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query which selects products from a table. A product can have multiple prices (think of various prices) and a default price.

Naturally, this is a one-to-many relation. I need to select the products which have a given price, or the default price - which means mutual exclusion. I know this can be done through separate queries and a WHERE (not) IN clauses or a union statement, but I'm convinced a more optimal way must be possible. My query currently looks like this:

```
SELECT products.*, products_prices.price 
FROM products RIGHT JOIN 
     products_prices ON (products.id = products_prices.productId) 
WHERE products_prices.businessId = ? 
OR    products_prices.businessId IS NULL // this needs to become mutual.
```

EDIT: I ended up using this query, which is a slightly modified version of Gordon Linoff's:

```
 SELECT distinct p.*, coalesce(pp.price, defpp.price)
 FROM products p LEFT JOIN 
      products_prices pp
      ON p.id = pp.productId and pp.businessId = ? left join
      products_prices defpp
      on p.id = defpp.productId and defpp.businessId is NULL
```

Comment: No. I don't understand. Perhaps an example will illustrate the problem.

Comment: You say "the given price," but price doesn't seem to be a parameter .. unless `businessId` is the price?

Comment: Sorry, you're right, the price isn't given. I meant to say that the productrecords with a businessId that isn't NULL have priority to the ones that don't (there would be duplicates, considering there's a record with a businessId that's NULL for every product)

Comment: In your questino, businessId is stored at the level of products, not product_prices.  Can you fix the question?

Comment: if product has several prices, should you show all prices?

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks, fixed that. Maybe that's why my distinct didn't work.

Comment: @AnatolyS no, i'm trying to show the price that has been set by a store with the RRP as a fallback. There can be multiple RRP's in the system though (dealers, business customers, ...), so that's why these must be stored in a separate table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the `products` table would have the default price and the `product_prices` table would have any other price.

You want to know where the default price is being used, meaning that there are no other prices.  For this, use a `left outer join`:

```
SELECT p.*, coalesce(pp.price, p.default_price)
FROM products p LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     products_prices pp
     ON p.id = pp.productId
WHERE pp.price = GIVENPRICE or pp.price is null
```

Based on your comment, you are storing the default prices in records with the business id being NULL.  In this case, I would do two joins to the prices table:

```
SELECT p.*, coalesce(pp.price, defpp.price)
FROM products p LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     products_prices pp
     ON p.id = pp.productId and pp.price = GIVENPRICE left outer join
     products_prices defpp
     on p.id = defpp.productId and defpp.businessId is NULL
```

The first join gets the price matching the given price.  The second gets the default price.  The first result is used, if present, otherwise the second is used.

Comment: I'm afraid that's wrong. The default price is in the products_prices table due to additional parameters, but default prices all have a businessId of NULL.

Comment: Surely the `where` clause in the second query is redundant?

Comment: @MarkBannister . . . Surely it is.  Thank you for catching that.

Comment: I slightly modified your query to change `pp.price = GIVENPRICE` into `pp.businessId = ?`, which nearly produces the result. The coalesce sometimes returns NULL though - specifically when businessid is null (and the records from 'pp' are missing). Thanks so far though!

Comment: @QuintenVK . . . I didn't have the right join condition for the default join.  Now that it is referencing `defpp` it should produce more reasonable results.