# Join to table without key to get related row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following CTE query inside a View that I need to `Group By` a field from the table `PS_PAYMENT_TBL` called `PYMNT_DT` as shown below, that has the below criteria:

```
BOX16DATA AS 
 ( SELECT A.VOUCHER_ID, A.PYMNT_TYPE , SUM(A.PAID_AMT) AS BOX16PAIDAMT , SUM(A.PYMNT_GROSS_AMT) AS WTHD_BOX16 , B.VENDOR_ID ,
  YEAR(C.PYMNT_DT) AS 'YEAR1' 
  FROM PS_PYMNT_VCHR_XREF A 
  INNER JOIN PS_VOUCHER B ON B.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND B.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID 
    INNER JOIN PS_PAYMENT_TBL C ON --(THIS WILL NOT WORK-->)--C.PYMNT_ID = A.PYMNT_ID
  WHERE A.PYMNT_TYPE = 'W' AND A.REMIT_VENDOR = '47860A'
  AND C.PYMNT_STATUS NOT IN ('S', 'V') 
  GROUP BY B.VENDOR_ID, A.PYMNT_TYPE, YEAR(C.PYMNT_DT) )
```

The problem is that all the rows retrieved from the above query will never have a `PYMNT_ID` in `PS_PAYMENT_TBL` or `PS_PYMNT_VCHR_XREF` (Because `PYMNT_TYPE` is = `'W'`) so therefore I cant use the above join (indented) on PYMNT_ID the way it is written now. However the `VOUCHER_ID` retrieved from the above query will always have a 2nd corresponding row in `PS_PYMNT_VCHR_XREF` that has a row with a `PYMNT_ID`. Here is an example of that:

[image]

What I need to be able to do is get the `PYMNT_ID` from the related row (that has the same voucher ID as retrieved in first query above) that I can then use to properly join for the `PS_PAYMENT_TBL` to get the `PYMNT_DT` field. My goal is to get the `PYMNT_ID` on the related row that I can use to join to `PS_PAYMENT_TBL`

I was thinking I could perhaps use another CTE to get the related row with the `PYMNT_ID` and then use that to join in my first query. I am not sure how I should do this though.

Comment: You need to join the same table twice with a different conditional using a left join. See here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526050/mutually-exclusive-values-in-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use another `CTE` to get the `PYMNT_ID` value for a given `VOUCHER_ID` e.g.

```
VIPI AS (
  SELECT VOUCHER_ID, MAX(PYMNT_ID) AS PYMNT_ID
  FROM PS_PYMNT_VCHR_XREF
  GROUP BY VOUCHER_ID
)
```

Then the `JOIN` in your `BOX16DATA` CTE becomes

```
FROM PS_PYMNT_VCHR_XREF A 
INNER JOIN PS_VOUCHER B ON B.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND B.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID 
INNER JOIN VIPI ON VIPI.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID
INNER JOIN PS_PAYMENT_TBL C ON C.PYMNT_ID = VIPI.PYMNT_ID
```

Comment: I altered the `VIPI` CTE slightly and self-joined `PS_PYMNT_VCHR_XREF` to itself and then added the result back into the `BOX16DATA` CTE. Thanks!

Comment: @Nick no worries - I'm glad this was helpful.